# Word Document to HTML

Tags: html

I have looked over the answers to what is the best to convert Word to HTML for free. What if I am willing to pay? The big issue is that these documents have several tables that need to be kept exact.  The background colors and cell alignment have to match the original.

Comment: This may be stating the obvious, but Word 2007 has an option to save documents as HTML - is this not suitable?

Comment: Perhaps he wants to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You're willing to pay?  Try http://word-to-html.com/ or the even more expensive http://www.solutionsoft.com/convert-word-to-html.htm

The main thing the other answers miss is that Word does a horrid job of producing HTML.  And otherwise reasonable tools like OpenOffice do an *even worse job*. The results are so incredibly bad there usual approach is two steps:

```
Step 1: Export HTML from word
Step 2: Post process the result to make it usable
```

An example (free) cleaner is http://word2cleanhtml.com/.

If you have the choice use Microsofts "Web Page, Filtered" rather than the full HTML (you'll be much happier).  Also consider a dark horse candidate: email the document to yourself via gmail, then "view as HTML".

Answer (score 2):

Word has an export (or save as) to HTML. Will that work?

It's Save As -- Other Formats -- Web Page, Filtered

Answer (score 1):

what version of word are you using?
Word has an option "Save as HTML".Isn't this enough?

Answer (score 1):

You would just do file>Save As> change file type to HTML.